# 3 months overstayed in Armenia

Tags: overstaying, armenia

I have Iranian passport and I have overstayed 3 months more than the 3 months visa-free, 6 months in sum. [Here.](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=AM&selDest=Armenia&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)

I don't have money to pay fine, what will happen in border if I want to leave Armenia? Will they capture and hold my luggages as bail for fine?

How can I avoid being jailed?

Answer (score 7):

I am not a lawyer specialized in Armenian migration laws, but it seems you will be forced to pay a [huge fine](http://www.arlis.am/documentview.aspx?docid=30350).

> առաջացնում է տուգանքի նշանակում` նվազագույն աշխատավարձի 100-ապատիկից մինչև 150-ապատիկի չափով:

Google translated:

> a fine equal to 100-fold to 150-fold of the minimum salary.

The minimum salary seems to be 55000 AMD.

What will most likely happen on a border crossing checkpoint is you will be detained and debt enforcement authority will be asked to cease the debt from you.

What you should really do is find a lawyer (perhaps some free law clinic?) and not rely on bits of advice from random people on the Internet.

Comment: It looks to me like the "100-fold to 150-fold" fine is for "Employers... to foreigners without residency status or work permit", while the fine for "Foreigners... without a valid visa or residence permit or invalid documents" is "50-fold to 100-fold" (still bad but less bad). Also [Չափով is sometimes translated as "lesser degree"](https://www.indifferentlanguages.com/translate/armenian-english/%D5%B9%D5%A1%D6%83%D5%B8%D5%BE), so it might be a fraction not a multiple - this is definitely one where the asker needs an informed native not random people on the internet!

Comment: A user, Nareg, posted this as an additional answer last year, yet it was inexplicably deleted by a moderator without anyone bothering to preserve the useful information, so I will paste it here without any personal understanding of its veracity: "I'm a couple months late to the party, but while the law states "times the minimum salary," it's times 1000 dram as commonly understood in Armenian court. "